# Remove leading space with \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings

When including listings with `\lstinputlisting`, spaces (or tabs) used for indentation of the code are kept, which is of course a good thing. But I want to document code line-by-line, so sometimes the context of the indentation gets lost, making it unnecessary. For long lines, this space could be used better. Is there an option to gobble spaces for input listings (the manual states that this feature is ignored for `\lstinputlisting`).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{backgroundcolor = \color{blue!10!white}} % show leading space

\begin{filecontents*}{code.lua}
function()
    -- indented comment
    local this = "test"
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[firstline=2, lastline = 3]{code.lua}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result (the blue background is there to visualize the leading space):
[image: Result with space]
I would like to remove the space on the left.

Comment: Do you require syntax highlighting features of `listings` or are you looking for a straight verbatim result?

Comment: Yeah, this is about code documentation, so I definitely need some features of `listings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See How to gobble characters section in `listings` document.
You can use `gobble=4` option to remove leading 4 characters
but it doesn't work with `\lstinputlisting`.

Consider using `minted` package which can process more languages.
You can write like this.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{backgroundcolor = \color{blue}}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=2, lastline = 3,gobble=4]{xxx.lua} % It doesn't work.
\begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    aaa
\end{lstlisting}
\inputminted[firstline=2,lastline=3,autogobble]{lua}{xxx.lua}
\end{document}
```

Note: `minted` package requires `-shell-escape` option and Python installed.

Comment: Thanks, then I will shift to minted. Do you know if there is a way to install styles locally? I can only find stuff about putting it in the distribution directory in the documentation.

Comment: tlmgr  have user mode. You can install to TEXMFHOME dir with user mode.